# stopping default submit action and trigger custom click on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using leadpages.net for building popups for my site.
They provide an anchor link and a script file source to get the popup on your page. I want to stop default action of form submission and fire my custom click event handler for processing data input as shown below.

But below never gets executed; tried all variations with the below code, even included event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation().
Please help; any insights what I am might be lacking.
Thanks in advance!!!

```
$('body').on('click', '#leadpages-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("here");
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with the said library? It's hard to understand why the code isn't working otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You're currently listening for a `click` on the form, not for the form to `submit`. Try something like this.

```
$('#leadpages-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("here");
});
```

Or, if your form is created dynamically, you'll have to do it similarly to your example.

```
//or document if the body is created dynamically as well
$('body').on('submit', '#leadpages-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("here");
});
```